# Extending jsTree list display to include associated data other than just a single string of text

Tags: jquery, html, css, json, jstree

Alright I have had a pretty much mixed experience so far with jsTree, but I have managed to get it running, configured with the right kind of data structure.

The JSON array of node data being passed from the backend to clarify the node structure

```
[

    {
        "id": 6,
        "parent_id": "null",
        "text": "ABC",
        "type": "root",
        "li_attr": {
            "data_role_id": "Owner"
        },
        "children": [
            {
                "id": 8,
                "parent_id": 6,
                "text": "KB",
                "type": "root",
                "li_attr": {
                    "data_role_id": "Admin"
                },...
```

Right now jsTree takes the `text` field from a node's JSON and displays it on the list. Now I have some more associated data from the backend on the list row like the image below. I figured I can send the metadata through HTML5 data attributes on the li node (for eg look above in `li_attr: {data_role_id: 'Admin'}`.

I'm trying to achieve this: 
[image: Tree structure]

I tried to achieve the result by injecting  `<table><tr><td>category</td></tr></table>` as a string with the `text` field as the data structure is being prepared in the backend. But it's very hacky and it completely messes up the separation of model and view.

What would be a good way to position this kind of data with the right kind of CSS?